# sample Apache Cordova on visual studio doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I followed the instruction on msdn to build the sample Apache Cordova, but when it is running, I am not getting and response from the output. The output is similar to the following image:

[image]

but there is no way to add / remove entry to the list.

I checked and found that index.html has the following lines:

```
 <button class="templateLeft templateToggle" ng-class="{'checked': toDoItem.done, 'unchecked': !toDoItem.done}" ng-mousedown="toggleToDoDone(toDoItem)"></button>
  <button class="templateLeft templateRemove" ng-click="removeToDo(toDoItem)"></button>
```

but there is no way to add new items to list?

What is wrong with this sample code that makes the UI doesn't work properly?

The sample uses angular.js

## Edit 1:

To find why the sample doesn't work and why I am not getting the correct result, I tried to debug the javascrip code. Based on my understanding, when the page which the code for it is as follow :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/frameworks/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <title>AngularJSToDo</title>

    <!-- AngularJSToDo references -->
    <link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body ng-app="xPlat">
    <section id="todoapp" ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
        <header id="header">
            <div id="headerBand"></div>
            <input id="new-todo" placeholder="What needs to be done?" ng-text-change="addToDo()" ng-model="newToDoText" autofocus>
        </header>
        <section id="main">
            <div id="todo-list">
                <div class="templateWrapper" ng-repeat="toDoItem in todos">
                    <div class="templateContainer">
                        <input class="templateTitle" ng-class="{crossedOut: toDoItem.done}" type="text" ng-text-change="changeToDoText(toDoItem)" ng-model="toDoItem.text" />
                        <h3 class="templateAddress">{{toDoItem.address}}</h3>
                        <button class="templateLeft templateToggle" ng-class="{'checked': toDoItem.done, 'unchecked': !toDoItem.done}" ng-mousedown="toggleToDoDone(toDoItem)"></button>
                        <button class="templateLeft templateRemove" ng-click="removeToDo(toDoItem)"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="templateBorder"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>

    <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The function in index.js is called:
The source for index.js is as follow:

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular.module('xPlat', ['xPlat.services', 'xPlat.controllers', 'xPlat.directives']);
angular.module('xPlat.directives', []);
angular.module('xPlat.controllers', []);
angular.module('xPlat.services', ['ngResource']);
})();
```

I put a breakpoints on this line:

```
angular.module('xPlat', ['xPlat.services', 'xPlat.controllers', 'xPlat.directives']);
```

and run the application, but the application did not stop on the line (apparently, the index.js is not loaded and if loaded, it is not run)

To see if the file exist in the correct place, I run the application and after it is loaded in ripple emulator, I change the url of the web browser to this:

```
 http://localhost:4400/scripts/index.js
```

and I can see the index.js text on screen.

why this function is not run when I load the page?

## Edit 2

After making some try and error, I found that I am getting these errors on JS console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
ripple.js (50,28958)


Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.16/ng/areq?p0=ToDoCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:6:417
    at Sb (http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:19:510)
    at La (http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:20:78)
    at http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:75:465
    at http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:57:178
    at q (http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:7:428)
    at M (http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:57:45)
    at g (http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:51:409)
    at g (http://localhost:4400/scripts/frameworks/angular.min.js:51:426)
angular.min.js (102,443)
```

It is appear from the first error that somefile is missing, but how can I find which file is missing?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but I suppose you ran into a known issue when debugging in ripple emulator. That is timing issue related to how visual studio attach the debugger. Try refresh the Chrome page, the debugger will be able to stop in deviceready  event. And try again to see if the break points can be hit. Instead of refreshing, we can also run window.location.reload() in javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you haven't gone through all parts in that guidance.

Please keep following and you will find the functions you need in services.js mentioned in section "add the data model". The data model and related functions are defined there.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to debug the code to find why it is not working and I found that the function in index.js is not called, I am going to update the question and add information about what I did and what I am getting.

Comment: Added some more detail information. Can you please look at it and help me with any suggestion that you may have?

Answer (score 0):

To add entries to the TODO list just click on “What needs to be done?”, start typing and press enter when done. To remove an entry just click on the entry and you will get the delete button on the left, click it and the item is gone and to mark an item as “Done” just click on the check box to the left.

I just ran the sample using Android Ripple Nexus (Galaxy) and it worked fine. The fact that you got to the initial page of the sample you attached tells me you are good to go. I also get the 404 on ripple but that doesn’t stop the sample to run (I have to investigate why of that error)

Finally if adding an entry doesn’t work for you, on Solution Explorer double click toDoCtrl.js file at www/scripts/controllers and set a breakpoint inside the ToDoCtrl.prototype.addToDo function, press F5 and try to add an entry, you should hit the breakpoint as soon as you enter a text and press enter.